# Tempus Dominus Timepicker show time after selecting date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using the Tempus Dominus Timepicker v5.0.1 with jquery 3.4.1 and the latest version of moment.js.  I have a form that has a registration start date and time and a registation end date and time.  I want the user to be able to select the date and after they click a date I want the time to appear automatically (the equivalent of clicking the clock button at the bottom).

I have my view:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationStartDate, new { @class = "font-weight-bold label-required" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationStartDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker-input", placeholder = RecruitClassResource.RegistrationStartDate, required = "required", id="datetimepicker1", data_toggle="datetimepicker", data_target="#datetimepicker1" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationStartDate)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationEndDate, new { @class = "font-weight-bold label-required" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationEndDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker-input", placeholder = RecruitClassResource.RegistrationEndDate, required = "required", id="datetimepicker2", data_toggle="datetimepicker", data_target="#datetimepicker2" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationEndDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datetimepicker-input').datetimepicker({
                icons: {
                    time: "far fa-clock"
                }
            });

            $('.datetimepicker-input').on('change.datetimepicker', function (e) {
                // Just a test to see when this event is fired
                alert(e.date);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I thought maybe the change.datetimepicker would be the event listener I was looking for, but it is fired the first time I click the textbox because the value changes from null to the current date.  I also am not sure what I would need to call for the time to appear when a date is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a JSFiddle for you, which does what you want, my friend -> https://jsfiddle.net/8ta5j6v7/2/.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 80px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
  var $picker = $("#datetimepicker1");
  $picker.on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
    // After the date is selected, I would like to switch to time view automatically / programmatically
    if (!e.oldDate && $picker.datetimepicker('useCurrent')) {
      // First time ever. If useCurrent option is set to true (default), do nothing
      // because the first date is selected automatically.
      return;
    }
    else if (
      e.oldDate &&
      e.date &&
      (e.oldDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') === e.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    ) {
      // Date didn't change (time did).
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1 [data-action="togglePicker"]').click();
    }, 300); // With a mini delay so that the animation doesn't fire right-away.
  });
});
```